# Какое сказуемое в предложении? (2)

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, тип-сказуемого

Действительно ли в данном предложении такая основа?

> **Многие из** этих **изменений вызывают** серьёзные нарушения в работе
> органов и систем.

Я бы выделил сказуемое ***вызывают нарушения***, а не просто ***вызывают***.
Как вы считаете? Прав ли сайт в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, современный синтаксис на ваше предложение вряд ли согласится. Переходный глагол влияет на независимо от него существующий объект реальности. Субъект совершает действие над объектом.

Я ем яблоко - идентичное по структуре предложение.

Comment: В русском языке существуют ОГИО, почему этот вариант нельзя считать одним из них?

Comment: Ну, если вы в них хорошо разбираетесь и есть такая цель - можете считать) Синтаксис - живое тело языка, а не набор кубиков. Вы спросили про основу - основу в современном русском выделяют так. Те люди, которые изучают огио, рассматривают иные градации смыслов. Так-то в синтаксисе теорий достаточно.

Comment: Просто тогда получается дичь. "Настроение будит воображение" - здесь методисты включают  в состав сказуемого "воображение". Вы же явно бы не стали здесь его включать в основу?

Comment: Дичь получится, есть хотеть универсальный набор кубиков на все случаи жизни. А его ну просто нет. Цель у вас какая? Кто ЦА, наблюдающая ваши выводы? Перед кем вы «его включаете в основу»? Если вы сами изучили теорию огио, легко их определяете в любом контексте, можете указать логику - выделяйте, конечно, это не запрещено. А если вы препод, ну смотря где вы, на филфаке или у экономистов факультативом.

Comment: Дело не в этом. Это задание ОГЭ. Я потому и привожу такие примеры, чтобы показать расхождение (т.к. обычно те же методисты включают существительное в состав сказуемого, а тут не включили). В данном случае не играло роли, выделишь ты это существительное в составе или нет, но само задание по ОГЭ, насколько я знаю, часто включает такие примеры, в которых принято видеть эти обороты.

Comment: Так вы б сразу и писали ситуацию в целом, со всеми деталями из комментов. Вам кажется, ответ будет честнее, что ли, если без подробностей спросить?) Без подробностей вам всегда ответят усреднённой нормой. А вас интересуют нюансы.

Answer (score 1):

*Многие из этих изменений **вызывают** серьёзные **нарушения** в работе органов и систем.*

Требуется определить вид сказуемого.

1. Работаем с учебником для педвузов Г.И. Кустова **Синтаксис современного русского языка** (издание 2013 года). Учебник выходил и позже (2017 год), в Интернете в свободном доступе 2004 год (стр. 67)
   [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)
2. ПРОСТОЕ ГЛАГОЛЬНОЕ СКАЗУЕМОЕ

ПГС может выражаться глагольными фразеологизмами и **глагольно-именными описательными оборотами**, которые по смыслу **эквивалентны глаголу** (мотать на ус; протянуть ноги; зарубить
себе на носу; пропустить мимо ушей; бить баклуши; точить лясы;
выжить из ума; высосать из пальца; прийти в себя; выйти из терпения; ***впасть в уныние*** (приуныть);  ***оказать помощь*** (помочь); ***проявлять заботу*** (заботиться).

2. **Вызвать нарушения – это нарушить.** Полагаю, что это ПГС, выраженное глагольно-именным описательным оборотом. Тогда выделяем сказуемое "вызывают нарушения" как простое глагольное сказуемое.

По крайней мере, такой вариант **выглядит вполне приемлемым** и описан в современном учебнике. А другое решение нужно обосновать, сославшись на источник.

Comment: Да, можно считать и так. Но огио твёрдо определимы только во фразеологизмах и устойчивых сочетаниях (потому их охотно и приводят как иллюстрацию). Вот «впасть в уныние», а куда ещё в том же смысле впадёшь? Вызывать нарушения =стать причиной - это и вызывать бессонницу / грусть / сплетни / наводнение / гастрит / задумчивость / войну. Трудно сказать, что это, по Леканту, глагол-призрак и что сочетание семантически неделимо. Я повторюсь, не считаю ваш ответ неверным, он верен. Я считаю это возможной трактовкой, как и в других случаях без очевидных критериев.

Comment: Из словаря: ВЫЗВАТЬ 3. только 3 л. что. Возбудить, породить, явиться причиной чего-л. Возможно,в своем третьем значении глагол образует неделимое сочетание, так как требует обязательного объекта.

Comment: Простите, не улавливаю вашу мысль. Глагол же переходный. В словаре Ож. во всех значениях  указана необходимость объекта.

Comment: Вернее сказать, не требует объекта, а порождает объект, является причиной объекта. Здесь не грамматика важна, а тесная семантическая связь с определенным объектом. Вызвать – это не позвать, а создать, инициировать, Значение у глагола (главного слова в словосочетании) переносное (метафорическое). А это одно из условий семантической неделимости сочетания .

Comment: Ну, это же и есть 3 словарное знач.=стать причиной. А как это нам помогает? Примеры из 1 коммента: вызывать бессонницу / грусть / сплетни / наводнение / гастрит / задумчивость / войну. Вы бы их все подчеркнули как сказуемое?

Comment: Трудно сказать. Или все, или никакие.  Чем вызвать болезнь отличается от вызвать нарушения в работе организма.  Суть не меняется, а грамматика считается разной.  Это как-то странно. Единственный критерий - это возможность замены сочетания глаголом.  Именно это называется ОГИО? Ну тогда пусть будет ОГИО в нашем случае, хотя это представляется очень условным,что нехарактерно для грамматики как точной науки

Comment: Да он не работает, критерий этот:( Звук вызывает колебание пера = колеблет. Голод вызывал недовольство матросов =рассердил. Неужели рука поднимется тут сказуемое выделять? Так что у меня с огио просто. Не фразеологизм, не устойчивое сочетание? Значит, объект. Ждём от науки критериев ясней )

Comment: Педагогов так учат, а филологов, возможно, по-другому. Может, все это годится для школьного уровня. Ладно, пусть сами разбираются со своими ОГИО.  У нас любят сначала создавать себе трудности, а потом их преодолевать